# How to write the columns header of the GridView in two or three lines instead of long one line?

Tags: gridview, asp.net-controls

I have a GridView with a lot of information and columns. The Header of each column is so long, so I want to write it in two or three lines instead of one line. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Description" 
                HeaderText="Description <br /> more stuff" 
                SortExpression="Description" 
                HtmlEncode="False" />
```